# removing a string from a vector C++

Tags: c++

In any card game, you lose your card from your hand when you play it, but with my limited knowledge in vectors I can't do it. Tried to pushback then popback to get rid of the string from the vector but doesn't work.

```
//Create vector to store deck names in & player's hands
    vector<string> Cards;    
    vector<string> P1Hand;

//Generate the deck of cards
    for (int i = 0; i < SuitNum;i++) //iterate through suits
    { 
       for (auto j : CardValue)
        {
            card = j.first + suits[i]; //declare card
            DeckValue[card] = CardValue[j.first];//add card to deck map and assign value
            Cards.push_back(card);  // add card to vector
            CardNum++;// raise card number for every card added to deck
        }
    }

//display cards for player 1
        while (CardNum > 13)
        {
           int RCard = rand()%CardNum;//generate a random number based on number of cards left in deck
           string DrawCard = Cards.at(RCard); // access a random card
           P1Hand.push_back(DrawCard); //add card to hand
           Cards.erase(Cards.begin() + RCard); // remove cards from vector so they cant be called twice
           CardNum--; //lower available cards
           cout<<"["<<DrawCard<<"]"; //print card and its value
        }
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Select Card to Play: ",cin>>PlayedCardP1;
```

What I tried:

```
P1Hand.push_back(PlayedCardP1); //delete last card to next deck
P1Hand.pop_back();
```

Basically, PlayedCardP1 should be removed from P1Hand

Comment: It was just me messing around with what I searched about vectors, it didn't work. I thought it would push PlayerCardP1 to the back and the pop would remove it from the vector.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove an item from a `std::vector` us an use [`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase), like already used in the code. That function requires an iterator. Luckely, [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), used for finding an element, gives you an iterator. Hence

```
P1Hand.erase(std::find(std::cbegin(P1Hand), std::cend(P1Hand), PlayedCardP1));
```

**NB** this invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the `end()` iterator. So take care it in an iterator loop. See the linked reference page.

Side note: `std::vector` is an array elements in memory. If you remove an element in the middle, all items after it will be shifted forward. That can become inefficient if done very often. An [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) is more efficient for that, but comes at the cost of more memory interactions when iterating and more storage for link pointers. You can test which one's better for you.
You could also look at [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set), which only can contain each value once. But it has other issues. Always test which container works better.

p.s. for `std::find` you need to `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: sorry for the noob question, how come your code gives me errors such as cbegin is not a member of std

Comment: @RogerL what compiler are you using?

Comment: i am using Dev C++

Comment: @RogerL that's not a compiler but an IDE. Dev C++ uses GCC. Set it to C++11 mode... or better: latest C++ version.

Comment: @RogerL alternatively, `std::cbegin(P1Hand)` is the modern version of `P1Hand.cbegin()`. same for `P1Hand.cend()`.

Comment: Turns out I just forgot to include <algorithm> lol. Many thanks man.

Comment: @RogerL you can thank me by accepting my post as the answer to your question